# plt.yscale does not show all items

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a dataframe.
When I plot the data as is, using this command:

```
data.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', legend=False)
```

I am getting this plot:

[image]

when I add

```
plt.xscale('log')
```

the data looks more linear (that is what I am trying to do).
[image]

But when I add

```
plt.yscale('log')
```

The plot looks weird:
 [image]

I also tried to give min and max values to Y:

```
plt.ylim((0, 100000))
```

But my data still looks weird

[image]

What am I doing wrong? why the yscale not working as the xscale?

Comment: Without seeing your data, I suspect the reason is because you seem to have a large number of 0 values for y. These can't be plotted on a log scale. You could try using `'symlog'` which gives you a mixed scale which is linear for a specified portion and logarithmic for the rest: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/scales/symlog_demo.html

Comment: Thanks!!!
It worked.
But I don't understand why the log scale did not work.
Even if I have a lot of values close to zero.
I can see that the scale of Y starts at 10^5 instead of 0